# Right triangle with angle

Tags: diagrams, asymptote, code

So my problem is simple, I just want to create a right triangle with angle 18. What I have so far is

[image: diagram]

Here's my code:

```
[asy]
size(300);
pair A = (0,0);
path B = dir(18);
path C = dir(90);
draw(A--B--C--cycle);
[/asy]
```

It does seem like it would be really simple to do, so if somebody could provide a solution that would be nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
    size(300);
    pair A = (0,0);
    pair B = dir(18);
    pair C = (xpart(B), 0);
    draw (A--B--C--cycle);
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

compile with latex, then `asy` on the file produced, then latex again.

[image]

- You can also write `pair C = (B.x, 0);` instead of using `xpart()`
- Note that `asy` is applying implicit scaling to everything for you because of the `size(300)` command at the top.

Answer (score 1):

With pure `tikz` is also simple. For 300 pt wide image you can use the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- ++ (18:315pt) |- cycle; % 315 is approx. 300/cos(18)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if asymptote or tikz is required or not, but IMO the easiest code is with pict2e. You can run trigonometric calculations from within this code using some packages that can do this, but the easiest is to use external software (Emacs calc for me).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\begin{picture}(12,5)(0,-1)
  \put(0,0){\line(951,309){10}}% 951=round(1000 cos(18)), 309=round(1000 sin(18))
  \put(0,0){\line(1,0){10}\line(0,1){3.24919696233}} % 3.24919696233=10 tan(18)
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Triangle rectangle]